# Spark unable to write to S3 Encrypted Bucket even after specifying the hadoopConfigs

Tags: amazon-emr

When i try to write to an S3 Bucket which is AES-256 Encrypted from my Spark Streaming App running on EMR it is throwing 403. For what ever reason the Spark Session is not honoring the "fs.s3a.server-side-encryption-algorithm" config option.

Here is the code i am using.

```
sparkSession.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key",accessKeyId);
sparkSession.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", secretKeyId);
sparkSession.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.server-side-encryption-algorithm","AES256");
```

When i use regular Java Code using AWS SDK i can upload the files without any issues.

Some how the Spark Session is not honoring this.

Thanks
Sateesh

Answer (score 0):

Able to resolve it. Silly mistake on my part.

We need to have the following property as well.

```
sparkSession.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.enableServerSideEncryption","true");
```